# InAppBrowser under Windows 8 doesn´t work

Tags: cordova, windows-8, sencha-touch, inappbrowser

I am working in a Cordova project under different platforms, for example iOS and Windows 8 tablet, this app works has support in browsers like  IE11 or Chrome, but I am having problems with the implementation with the InAppBrowser plugin, under W8 tablet doesn´t work and if you do "tap" in different buttons to open attachments, this event doesn´t work... What is the problem??!

I have a class to manage this with the next code...

```
openLinkInNewWindow: function (url) {
    var link = Ext.getDom(this.getLinkId()),
        clickevent = document.createEvent('Event'),
        hash = location.hash;

    if (Ext.browser.is.Standalone) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastVisitRouteForLunchApp', hash);
    }
    if (Ext.os.deviceType == "Tablet" && Ext.os.name == "Windows") {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }
    if (Ext.os.deviceType == "Tablet" && Ext.os.name == "iOS") {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    } else {
        link.href = url;
        Ext.Function.defer(function () {
            clickevent.initEvent('click', true, false);
            link.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  (code is based in Sencha Touch Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the next code added in the index.html

```
function isPhoneGap() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

function openPage(link) {
    if (isPhoneGap() == true) {
        var ref = window.open(link.href, '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewPortScale=yes');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And now it is working correctly and I am so happy!!!  :-)